# How to extend a P5JS class in Svelte

Tags: typescript, svelte, p5.js, sveltekit

I haven't asked many questions on SO, so please bare with me if I don't follow all the rules. I'll try my best to explain my problem.

I'm using Sveltekit ([`create-svelte`](https://github.com/sveltejs/kit/tree/master/packages/create-svelte)) and P5JS ([`p5-svelte`](https://p5-svelte.netlify.app/docs/get-started)) to create a canvas and a UI to control parameters of the P5JS sketch. I would like to write a class (Node) that extends a P5JS class (Vector).

I import type Vector from p5, that works fine, but don't know how to import Vector as a module (not sure that's the correct description). The problem is that when I try to extend the Vector class I get an error:

```
<script lang="ts"\>
    import P5 from "p5-svelte";
    import type { Sketch } from "p5-svelte";

    import type { Vector } from "p5"; // import the type Vector from p5 - that works great, as @types/p5 is installed (see package.json)
    
    // import { Vector } from "p5"; // This doesn't work, p5 not found: "Internal server error: Failed to resolve import "p5" from "src/routes/+page.svelte". Does the file exist?"
    
    // import { Vector as p5Vector } from "p5"; // This doesn't work. Same message.
    
    let width = 55;
    let height = 55;
    
    const sketch: Sketch = (p5) => {
        p5.setup = () => {
            p5.createCanvas(400, 400);
            const myVector: Vector = p5.createVector(100, 100); // that works
            console.log(myVector.x); // 100
        };
    
        p5.draw = () => {
            p5.ellipse(p5.width / 2, p5.height / 2, width, height);
        };
    };
    
    // Here's the problem. This isn't working, "ReferenceError: Vector is not defined". If I import Vector as a type, it says "'Vector' cannot be used as a value because it was imported using 'import type'.ts(1361)". Also using p5.Vector doesn't work.
    class Node extends Vector {
        constructor(x, y) {
            super(x, y);
            this.x = x;
            this.y = y;
        }
    }

\</script\> …
```

(for full file, see [+page.svelte](https://github.com/andipollok/test-svelte-p5-vector/blob/main/src/routes/%2Bpage.svelte))

Also, adding p5 additionally as a dev dependency doesn't work with this setup, as it throws an error even if the library is only imported (Error 500 "window not defined").

I'm sure I'm missing something obvious.

The whole example is on [Github](https://github.com/andipollok/test-svelte-p5-vector) and deployed [here](https://test-svelte-p5-vector.vercel.app/) (gives an Error 500 of course).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The type package will not help you at all if you want to extend a runtime type (i.e. a class). The correct method would be the following:

```js
import p5 from 'p5';

class Node extends p5.Vector { ... }
```

The type package would supply information about what `p5.Vector` looks like but the value has to come from `p5` itself.

The error about "window not defined" means that the package is not compatible with server-side rendering (SSR) which does not have access to the `window` object which is provided by the browser on the client.

You could [turn off SSR](https://kit.svelte.dev/docs/page-options#ssr) if that is really necessary by setting the following in a `+layout.ts`/`+page.ts`:

```js
export const ssr = false;
```

Maybe you do not necessarily need the vector implementation of `p5`?

Comment: Thank you! That worked. I updated the repo with the solution!

Comment: I would like to use the vector implementation of p5 as my Node class builds on it and uses mult(), pow(), limit() etc. based on the [examples from Generative Gestaltung](http://www.generative-gestaltung.de/2/sketches/?02_M/M_6_1_03).

Comment: Well, there are probably many implementations of such math constructs. but your choice. If this sufficiently answered the question you can accept it using the checkmark outline to the side.

Comment: Looking at performance, I'm sure there are better implementations for vector operations than the ones in P5. But all examples are using those from P5, so I'm sticking with it. And thanks for pointing me to the checkmark to accept the answer, this is my first post so I wasn't familiar with the concept.